# Configuring Dropbox on Ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, directory, dropbox

I've got a Ubuntu server running on an old laptop. The OS is on a 4GB USB drive and I use a SATA drive attached for storage.

Now I wanted to set up Dropbox on this machine. I've got it running using this guide: http://www.byteindia.com/internet/install-dropbox-on-linux/482/. But I haven't synched yet because there won't be enough room in my home dir. My /home is on my 4GB USB since I never use it and all my data is on the 2TB drive mounted in /media/.

What is the best way to set this up? Dropbox doesn't support moving the folder in Linux yet. I found a script to move the folder but it seems outdated. Perhaps I can use symlinks in some clever way? Or maybe move my /home folder to my SATA drive?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've found my (previously via GUI) configured path in `~/.dropbox/info.json`

Comment: @Seth The answer to "how is this an answer" is: Edit the file ...

Answer (score 2):

You gave the answer yourself,
Use symlinks.
Move your Dropbox folder to your HDD, then create a symlink in your home folder
For example:
          ln -s /media/MyHDD/Dropbox /home/yourname/